# Why do decorators have to apply(this) to a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, this, decorator

I've been reading a lot about this in javascript context and been trying to understanding decorator code. Whenever I look at decorator code, such as below, it always applies this input function to 'this' even though the input function does not make any references to 'this'. Why is that? Is it necessary to apply a function to 'this' in a decorator always? It also says in many places that the decorator cannot be an arrow function because of the binding to this. Can someone why that would affect the function?

```
function doSomething(name) {
  console.log('Hello, ' + name);
}

function loggingDecorator(wrapped) {
  return function() {
    console.log('Starting');
    const result = wrapped.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log('Finished');
    return result;
  }
}

const wrapped = loggingDecorator(doSomething);
```

Comment: "*even though the input function does not make any references to 'this'*" - but what if it did? The point is that the decorator cannot know, so it always has to play safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is necessary to give the wrapped function a correct `this` when it's called as a method of some object, consider:

```js
function loggingDecorator(wrapped) {
    return function () {
        console.log('Starting');

        //const result = wrapped() // <-- this doesn't work
        const result = wrapped.apply(this, arguments); // <-- this does

        console.log('Finished');
        return result;
    }
}

class T {
    constructor() {
        this.property = 42;
    }

    someMethod() {
        console.log(this.property)
    }
}


T.prototype.someMethod = loggingDecorator(T.prototype.someMethod);

t = new T;
t.someMethod();
```

Here, our decorated function is called with `this` equal to `t` and have to pass this `this` down to the original method, otherwise it won't be able to resolve `this.property`. Obviously, if the original function doesn't use `this` in any way, this is not necessary, still, it's a good practice to always write decorators with `apply`, so that they can be used in any context.

Comment: Thanks i see. I was just curious as to why it seemed necessary in all the examples 
none of which had a reference to `this` but I guess it's just good practice

Comment: @VikramKhemlani: yes, but note that actual decorators ('@' syntax), as implemented in TS, don't even work with standalone functions, which makes `apply` mandatory.